# Mopidy Installation Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, mopidy

Installing on Mac High Sierra, through a fresh installation of Brew, following the instructions on the website to the letter. It throws this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mopidy", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'Mopidy==2.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Clearly it's not finding the distro even though it's in the default location with all my other packages. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you done

```
brew tap mopidy/mopidy
```

before running:

```
brew install mopidy
```

??

Following these steps I manage to install it successfully.
I am on `OS X 10.13.3`

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks though.